# Monad m => a -> [a -> m a] -> m a

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, and I wonder if there's a better way to find out if one duplicates library functionality than Hoogle?

Case in point: I have a number of functions `f :: Monad a => a -> m a` that I want to chain together, like

```
f1234 x = (return x) >>= f1 >>= f2 >>= f3 >>= f4
```

But I'd rather write

```
chain :: Monad m => a -> [a -> m a] -> m a
chain = foldl (>>=) <$> return
f1234 = (flip chain) [f1, f2, f3, f4]
```

It seems very basic, does the base libary offer something equivalent to `chain`?

Comment: An alternative to hoogle is, with a bit of intuition, guessing the most appropriate module and then browsing its documentation page.  You might find some other way of shortening your code, or find some other very usefull function you want to remember. This tactic works best with the base package and then for the 'abstraction' modules (like Monad and Applictive, later the more advanced Foldable and Traversable) and parameterized patternlike datatypes (e.g. Maybe, List). Though you could also do it for more used datatypes (For me, Map/Set and later the Monad Transformers).

Comment: `chain = foldl (>>=) . return` is ***so much clearer***, IMHO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hoogle's good for this, and definitely the right tool for finding a function with the same type.

Given that it's straightforward, and it's not turning up in any of the usual places, you may as well write it yourself as import it from some obscure module, partly because you won't import a whole load of other things.

*(Aside: Some packages don't seem to be searchable from hoogle, so if you know the function, module or package name you're after and hoogle doesn't know, use hayoo.)*

I'd like to plug

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
```

from `Control.Monad`. It's the composition operator I always kept wanting till I found it. It's a more natural way to work with monads than `>>=` in my view.

You could even use it directly, it's so clear:

```
f1234 = f1 >=> f2 >=> f3 >=> f4
```

It shows up if you hoogle for `(a -> m a) -> (a -> m a) -> (a -> m a)`, so a future strategy if you're looking for something that combines a list of something is to search for a function that combines two and use one of the `fold` functions.

Thus

```
chain' :: Monad m => [a -> m a] -> a -> m a
chain' = foldr (>=>) return

f1234 = chain' [f1,f2,f3,f4]
```

or

```
chain'' :: Monad m => a -> [a -> m a] -> m a
chain'' = flip $ foldr (>=>) return
```

if you prefer, but yours is fine anyway.

Comment: Note that `f1 >=> f2 >=> f3 >=> f4` is more generic than `chain' [f1,f2,f3,f4]` as it allows to compose `a -> m b` and `b -> m c`.